# How to backup dspace contents properly?

Tags: backup, dspace

at dspace 3.2

i tried this.....`pg_dump/psql (DB backup)`

backup:

```
pg_dump -U username -f backup.sql database_name
```

restore:

```
psql -d database_name -f backup.sql
```

it works something like import DB.....stating alter table, create table etc.
i restarted tomcat.....but only communities are came....when i enter in to that communities no records found. i already copied the assetstore at /home/dspace/

What are the minimum backup items for dsapce include DB....and how to do that properly....backup & restore??

Comment: Did you tried to reindex (eg dspace index-discovery -b) after you restore your database?

Comment: No....and tried it on dspace 4.2. is that problem?

Comment: Please give me in steps.....i am really stuck there!!

Comment: As noted by @euler, you need to do a reindex after the pg_restore.

Answer (score 2):

perhaps this link from the documentation of DSpace can help you: [Multi-Version Upgrade Tips and Tricks](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC4x/Multi-Version+Upgrade+Tips+and+Tricks)

Take a look at **Option 2: Install Fresh and Upgrade your Data**, there is a step by step instruction there.

Good luck.

Comment: hello all...i was not active many days...
recently i followed some experiments related with this restore. i got some in formation [link]http://mishravk.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/About_DSpace.pdf
but while doing i couldnot perform restore... i nly done backup but i couldn't find [dspace-source]/dspace/etc/postgres/database_schema_3-4.sql dspace-upgrade.
i only have till 18-3.sql version. So how can i perform this database updation and restore the entire instance to another pc...??